# validate the date field value

Tags: javascript

I have one date field in form. I need to validate the date. need to calculate the selected date from today's date.

```
if(selecteddate > 7days from today's date)
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

[image]

How can I achieve this.?

Comment: can you show the format of the selected date you are receiving

Comment: @HimanshuTanwar added in question. the format is mm/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy or mm/d/yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below

```
        var n=7; //number of days to add. 
        var today=new Date(); //Today's Date
        var requiredDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+n)

        if ((new Date(selecteddate ).getTime()) > (new Date(requiredDate).getTime())) 
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following:

```
var required_date = new Date();
required_date.setDate(required_date.getDate() + 7);

var selected_date = new Date(selected_date);

if (selected_date.getTime() > required_date.getTime()) {
    return true;
else
  return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user is entering in the format mm/dd/yyyy, m/d/yyyy, or mm/d/yyyy, you will need to do some reformatting to get a Date object. `moreThanSevenDays()` is a function that does this reformating and then checks if it is more than 7 days from today.

```
function moreThanSevenDays(selectedDateString) {

    //add a "0" to front of single digit months or dates
    var dateArr = selectedDateString.split("/");
    for (var i=0; i<dateArr.length; i++) {
        if(dateArr[i].length == 1) {
            dateArr[i] = "0"+dateArr[i]
        }
    }

    //get Date object from selected date
    var selectedDate = new Date(dateArr[2]+"-"+dateArr[0]+"-"+dateArr[1]);

    //get Date object for 7 days from now
    var today = new Date();
    var limit = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()+7)

    //check which is greater
    if(selectedDate.getTime() > limit) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }    
}

moreThanSevenDays("5/2/2016") //returns true
```